# С2512. Person: нет подходящего конструктора по умолчанию.E0291.для класса"Person" не существует конструктор по умолчанию

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, конструктор

Как исправить ошибки С2512 и E0291,строка 29?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Person
{

protected:
string name;
string surname;
public:
Person(string n, string s)
{
    name = n;
    surname = s;
}
void Print(Person p) 
{
    cout << "Name - " << name << endl;
    cout << "Surname - " << surname << endl;
}
~Person();

};
class Student:public Person
{
protected:
    string specialty;
    double grade;
public:
Student(string s,double g){
    specialty = s;
    grade = g;
}

   

~Student();
};
int main()
{
Person* per = new Person("name", "surname");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем конструкторе `Student`

```
Student(string s,double g){
    specialty = s;
    grade = g;
}
```

не указан вызов конструктора базового класса, а значит, в качестве такового будет использован конструктор по умолчанию `Person::Person()`. У вас такого нет, и сгенерировать его компилятор не может - поскольку есть `Person::Person(string n, string s)`. Что компилятору остается, кроме как жаловаться на жизнь?...

Вы должны либо добавить конструктор по умолчанию `Person::Person()`, либо переписать

```
Student(string s,double g):Person(?,?) {
```

Здесь `?` - какие-то аргументы типа `string`, ну, а какие и откуда их брать - это уж думайте сами исходя из своей задачи... Вы сейчас создаете безымянного студента - *это намек*.

И еще - не надо эти присваивания в конструкторе, используйте инициализацию:

```
Person(string n, string s):name(n),surname(s){}
```

И снова - зачем вам копировать лишний раз строки? Передавайте их по ссылке:

```
Person(const string& n, const string& s):name(n),surname(s){}
```

То же относится и к `Student`.

И кстати, а где же тело деструктора? Если деструктор ничего особого делать не должен - или пишите

```
~Person(){};
```

или

```
~Person() = default;
```

а то при линковке будут проблемы, если соберетесь память освободить. И это замечание относится и к `Student` тоже.

Дальше смотреть не буду, а то ответ никогда не закончу :)